# Why I can't change the height of CircleAvatar or other circular widgets in AppBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-appbar

I am trying to put a `CircleAvatar` inside the `AppBar` in the actions list, but the CircleAvatar will stick its height to that of the AppBar, making it impossible to resize it and to keep it circular. I already tried wrapping it inside a Container or SizedBox, but it didn't work.

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HoursScreenEmployee extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white10,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: false,
        actions: [
          CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: NetworkImage("https://picsum.photos/500/300"),
            maxRadius: 15,
            minRadius: 15,
          ),
        ],
        title: Text(
          "La Chance ",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: "Masiva",
            fontSize: 27,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the `CircleAvatar` in a `Row`:

```
actions: [
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 60,
                width: 60,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage:
                      NetworkImage("https://picsum.photos/500/300"),
                  maxRadius: 15,
                  minRadius: 15,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
```

Result:

[image: res]

Answer (score 0):

To change the height and width of image inside circle avatar, do this:

```
                   CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 20,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 15,
                        backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                          ImageAssets.micIcon,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```